# VB.Net Report viewer parameters

Tags: vb.net, parameters, filter, report, reportviewer

I added a Parameter to report.rdlc called "ReportTitle".  It is text and allows blank values and nulls.  I have tried different ways to pass the parameter value to no avail.  This is what I've tried so far:

```
  Dim parReportParam1 As New ReportParameter("ReportTitle", "THIS IS MY TITLE")
  ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {parReportParam1})
```

Does not work!

```
    Dim params(0) As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter
    params(0) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter("ReportTitle", "THIS IS MY TITLE")
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
```

Nothing!

```
    Dim params(0) As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter
    params(0) = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter
    params(0).Name = "ReportTitle"
    params(0).Values.Add("THIS IS MY TITLE")
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
```

Nope!

I don't know what to try anymore.  Do I have to set something on the reportviewer or on the designer to allow parameter values.  Any help is greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Try to post your error messages, or read them

Comment: There are no errors.  The report displays but the parameter is used as the title doesn't show anything.

Comment: Did you set that field in the designer?

Comment: Yes I added it in the designer.  It is called "ReportTitle".  I dragged it to the header section of the report and I am using it as the title of the report.  It shows as "[@ReportTitle]".

Comment: By the way I am using the Visual Studio 2013 Community edition.  I don't know if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found The Aswer, You need to remember to put parameters after you pick the path to the Report never before.

I had exacly the same problem, everything was fine till I put parameters to the Raport and I had spent two hours before I found the cause.

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I never replied back until now.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    Dim paramStoreNo As New ReportParameter("StoreNo", iSTORE_NO)
    Dim reportparameters() As ReportParameter = {paramStoreNo}
    InventoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Inventory, iSTORE_NO)
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportparameters)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe accidentally you have set available values for parameter to just `null` or some other values in `report.rdlc`. If so goto parameter properties and set `Available Values` to `None` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that you cant see your parameter value at your report, Can you try adding a refresh in your report viewer code page.

Add this at the end of your code

```
Reportviewer.localreport.refresh()
```

The problem might be because the page loaded before the application finished passing the values, so refresh it so it can reload with the parameter values at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code and it works fine:

```
For Each param As WinForms.ReportParameterInfo In ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetParameters()


If param.name = "ReportTitle" Then

 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New WinForms.ReportParameter(param.Name, "THIS IS MY TITLE"))

End If

Next

Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```