# How to pass parameters to ReportViewer with vba

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webforms, reportviewer

I Have a report using report viewer/vba and I am trying to pass a parameter to it using the code:

```
    Dim parameters(0) As ReportParameter
    parameters(0) = New ReportParameter("Model", "XBR-32")
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters)
```

and when I execute the webform it goes like this for more than 10 minutes an the report does not open:

[image]

I don't know if I am passing the parameters in the wrong way. can someone help me, please?

Comment: I don't believe this is the issue.  Is it a really big query?  Can you post the section where you open the report also?  What happens when you open it without the parameter? [This may help also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511730/c-sharp-reportviewer-local-report-with-parameter)

Comment: Hi. No it is not a big query. When I delete the parameter and open the report, it works fine! follow the section: 

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   
        Dim parameters(0) As ReportParameter
        parameters(0) = New ReportParameter("Model", "XBR-32")
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters)


    End Sub

Comment: First things first, work out what language you're using. Get rid of the language from the title - that's what tags are for - and change the language tag if this is really VBA rather than VB.NET. As the tag descriptions state, they are different languages and you don't use each for the other.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I think based on the code content that it's VB.NET not VBA.  The sub call has parens around the parameters, in VBA it would not.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for that but it is VB.NET and I don't know for sure what happened but if I pass the parameters on a button to call the report it works, but on the method Load it does not. anyway, I create a button to call instead of load the report when I open the page. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to remember to put parameters after you pick the path to the Report never before.

See the similar question:[VB.Net Report viewer parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27806245/vb-net-report-viewer-parameters)

Comment: that's interesting, I will check that. Thanks!